# Why does Leakcanary state that a weakreference caused a leak?

Tags: android, weak-references, leakcanary

LeakCanary reported a leak:

```
LeakingInstance(referenceKey=c0b17865-2174-494c-861b-e8bd96a894b2, referenceName=, instanceClassName=superfreeze.tool.android.userInterface.intro.IntroActivity, watchDurationMillis=5162, retainedDurationMillis=159, exclusionStatus=WEAKLY_REACHABLE, leakTrace=
┬
├─ android.view.ViewRootImpl$AccessibilityInteractionConnection
│    Leaking: NO (it's a GC root)
│    ↓ ViewRootImpl$AccessibilityInteractionConnection.mViewRootImpl
│                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.ref.WeakReference
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Matches exclusion field java.lang.ref.WeakReference#referent
│    ↓ WeakReference.referent
│                    ~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.ViewRootImpl
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ViewRootImpl.mContext
│                   ~~~~~~~~
╰→ superfreeze.tool.android.userInterface.intro.IntroActivity
​     Leaking: YES (RefWatcher was watching this and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
, retainedHeapSize=null)
```

But the first entry (AccessibilityInteractionConnection) seems to only hold a weak reference (second entry) to the third entry, and therefore the ViewRootImpl and IntroActivity should be garabage collected! Where does this leak come from?

In the LeakCanary documentation [it says:](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals/#analyzing-the-heap)

> Leak trace is another name for the shortest strong reference path from
>   garbage collection roots to a retained object

But I do not even have a strong path here!

What did I understand wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In v2 alpha2 LeakCanary started including WeakReferences into it's computation of shortest paths: https://square.github.io/leakcanary/changelog/#version-20-alpha-2-2019-05-21

In retrospect that was a mistake and was later removed. You need to update LeakCanary.

Comment: Why do you think that it was removed later? I could find nothing about this. Also it says "now reporting leaks that only go through weak references (previously reported as 'no path to instance')" in the changelog, which sounds like there is no other path to my leaked instance. But why did it leak, then?

Comment: I remove those because they introduced a lot of confusion. An instance only reachable by weak references is weakly reachable and therefore not leaking. All major heap analysis tools ignore weak refs when computing shortest paths. You can still add them back by tweaking the LeakCanary config.

Comment: @Piere-Yves-ricau How can it be that my activity leaked, then?

Comment: I have no idea, you might want to check with the new version.